# Jeff Schaller-Why do you put your picture up on every edit?

Tags: discussion, editing

I see the posters picture goe up but why do we havew someone who merely edits posts finding it necessary to get his picture out front big noting himself?

Thats a bit overboard from a moderator

Answer (score 19):

The profile picture (including the username and reputation points etc.) of the most recent user editing a post, whether moderator or not, is attached to the post together with information about when the edit was made.  This is not in any way special to Jeff's edits, moderator edits or edits made by other people.

If someone else subsequently edits the post, the profile image is updated; if the original poster edits the post, the indicator reduces to a timestamp.

This applies to both questions and answers.

Another thing that may be relevant to know is that moderators may possibly (but not necessarily) do a bit *more* editing than other users. This means that you may be more likely to see our profile pictures crop up here and there.  This is, after all, part of what a moderator does. Apart from us, you are also more likely to see users with high "reputation" do more edits than others. The ability to edit other people's post *without review* [is a privilege](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that users with above 2k reputation points have.

This is how this site works.

See also [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) (FAQ on the main Meta site).  The thing you are wondering about is called an "Edit indicator" there.

Comment: All good thought it was personal agrandment.